# Is "currentPlaybackTime" property of MPMoviePlayerController a private API

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-privateapi

I am not sure about this private API thing.

Is the property `currentPlaybackTime`, which is in the `MPMediaPlayback` Protocol of the `MPMoviePlayerController` a private API?

I am asking, because this property is working fine but it is not listed in the `MPMoviePlayerController` Reference. Is it then a private one?

By the way: in the `MPMoviePlayerController` it is listed in the reference

(I did read somewhere that the private APIs methods/properties typically have a underscore before their names, like `_currentPlaybackTime`. Don't know if this is really right.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look in the documentation, If it's there, it's documented and available. If not, it's private.

> `currentPlaybackTime`
>
> The current position of the playhead. (required)
>
> ...
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 3.2 and later.

Comment: Ah, ok. This is the way how it is defined. Thank you!